# System.ArgumentException on Infragistics TabManager

Tags: tabs, infragistics, argumentexception

i got the folowing error after adding new tab in infragistics's tab manager

"System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid"

this error shows on designer, so I can't debug it..

it does no accur immeadiatly after adding a new tab, just after rebuilding or trying to run the program

any ideas about what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

According to the support tests the issue is resolved in current service releases of the controls - [Link to same issue in Infragistics forum](http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/41053/277979.aspx)